# Regarding MuiPickersUtilsProvider : Can I change the timezone

Tags: reactjs, frontend, momentjs, material-ui, datetimepicker

I want to change the timezone according to the selection user makes. I am setting a default timezone using
`moment.tz.setDefault("user timezone")` and passing moment and MomentUtils as my props in the MuiPickersUtilsProvider. But it is not showing the desired behavior.

```
<MuiPickersUtilsProvider moment={moment} utils={MomentUtils}>
<KeyboardDateTimePicker
/>
</MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Passing in moment to `MuiPickersUtilsProvider` isn't doing anything: https://material-ui-pickers.dev/getting-started/usage

```
const [dateTime, setDateTime] = useState(moment())

const handleDateTimeChange = inputDate => {
  setDateTime(moment(inputDate))
}

return (
  <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={MomentUtils}>
    <KeyboardDateTimePicker
      label={'Select DateTime'}
      value={dateTime}
      onChange={handleDateTimeChange}
    />
  </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
)
```

If the timezone isn't getting set, or you want more flexibility to change the timezone, you can use `moment().zone(selectedTimezone)`